# How can i integrate cloud9 with cloudbees?

Tags: integration, cloudbees, cloud9-ide

How can i integrate Cloud9 IDE directly with Cloudbees. According to 
https://www.cloudpipes.com/integrations/cloud9/cloudbees, i can use cloudpipe to make this integration. Cloudpipe is still very young, i would prefer a direct integration if it is possible. Since i only have free account both on cloud9 and cloudbees, i would also glade to know, how can i establish the integration for free try accounts or it is only possible for supported accounts.

Your comments are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

CloudBees only provides a plugin for the integration with Eclipse. However, Intellij, for example, or the one that you say have also developed some tools to be better integrated with CloudBees services.  If there is a tool called Cloudpipe, but you don't want to use it because it is too young, I guess then you will not enjoy the integration as I think there are not more tools for it.

Maybe, the only thing you can do is to push your code from cloud9-ide to forge CloudBees repositories and then trigger the hook on Jenkins so as to build and deploy to the runtime environment once your build is successful.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. I will try your suggestion with the Cloudpipe. What i am concerned about is all the privacy issues, since i am looking for an end-to-end solution to replace the current on-premise infrastructure in my organisation in public service. One more third-party means always a lot of work for me to check out the privacy.